# Count values of a particular column and display it monthwise and partwise

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

```
CREATION_DATE   REJECTED_REASON                        PART_NAME                                             REJECTED_QTY                                        
03-03-2014  Metal chips in port face            PEGEOUT 1.8 CYLINDER HEAD CASTING H29                              15
03-03-2014  Angular hole Shrinkage              PEGEOUT 1.8 CYLINDER HEAD CASTING H29                              7
01-05-2014  5th  cap side dross                 CYL.HEAD VM MOTORI-4 CYL TESTA CILINDRI LAVORATA                   23
01-05-2014  Casting broken                      CYL.HEAD VM MOTORI-4 CYL TESTA CILINDRI LAVORATA                   3
01-05-2014  Bend in dand                        CYL . HEAD VM MOTORI-4 CYL TESTA CILINDRI LAVORATA                 11           
01-05-2014  Bend in casting                     CYL . HEAD VM MOTORI-4 CYL TESTA CILINDRI LAVORATA                 17
07-05-2014  Angular hole Shrinkage              EATON REAR HOUSING H-99                                            10
08-05-2014   Unclean                            CASTING CYLINDER HEAD 01 OF KOHLER H-185                           9
08-05-2014  Angular hole Shrinkage              CASTING CYLINDER HEAD 01 OF KOHLER H-185                           1
08-05-2014  Bend                                CASTING CYLINDER HEAD 01 OF KOHLER H-185                           20
12-11-2014  Shrinkage on top face               GEAR BOX HOUSING ITL CLUTCH - ITL                                  15
12-11-2014  Casting damage                      GEAR BOX HOUSING ITL CLUTCH - ITL                                  5 
13-11-2014  1st Exhaust Port Core Shift         PIAGGIO 3 VALVE CYLINDER HEAD CASTING                              22
06-01-2015   Shrinkage in spark plug            G-30 CYLINDER HEAD REAR CASTING                                    14
08-01-2015  1st cap side dross                  G-30 CYLINDER HEAD REAR CASTING                                    6
08-01-2015   Unclean                            G-30 CYLINDER HEAD REAR CASTING                                    2 
08-01-2015   Shrinkage in spark plug            G-30 CYLINDER HEAD REAR CASTING                                    12 
13-01-2015  1st cap side dross                  G-30 CYLINDER HEAD REAR CASTING                                    1
13-01-2015  1st Exhaust Port Core Shift         G-30 CYLINDER HEAD REAR CASTING                                    9
13-01-2015   Shrinkage in spark plug            G-30 CYLINDER HEAD REAR CASTING                                    10
```

Suppose I have above values in a particular table.Now  I need to sum up the rejection quantity and display rejection reasons as columns and rejection quantity as values monthwise as well as partwise 
Suppose I need the data for May 2014.The report output for the above list of values should be:-

```
PART NAME                                         5th cap side dross    Casting Broken  Bend in Casting   Bend in Dand  Angular Hole Shrinkage  Unclean Bend
CYL . HEAD VM MOTORI-4 CYL TESTA CILINDRI LAVORATA         23                   3             17               11                   0               0   0
CASTING CYLINDER HEAD 01 OF KOHLER H-185                   0                    0             0                0                    1               9   20
EATON REAR HOUSING H-99                                    0                    0             0                0                    10              0   0
```

Please help me and guide me in implementing this task in oracle through sql or pl sql.

Comment: This looks like dynamic pivot, not resolved in oracle, as far as i know

Comment: @jarlh-I tried using group by but I am unable to get the output in the required format.Please provide me the sample code.

Comment: @Aramillo-Even i think so but I am not sure about it.

Comment: pivot may be in oracle now? sorry I use MSSQL mostly http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html

Comment: You should Group By Part_Name then do Case statements for the Reasons e.g. SUM(Case when Rejected_Reason = '5th cap side dross' then 1 else 0 end) as [5th cap side dross] - this being said I'm working in SQL Server so don't know if this works in Oracle

Comment: @ChristianBarron - SQL Server has `PIVOT`, which would simplify that quite a bit.  Recent versions of Oracle do too.  Although the one problem is, you have to give an explicit number of columns, or use dynamic SQL to discover the count you need first...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best would be to use dynamic pivot as Aramillo said. Oracle has something like that, it's **pivot xml** clause, but I have some query for you which do the job dynamically without xml operations. As you said you need only display report so after some formatting the output of below query will be appropriate for your case:

```
            select part_name , 
rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement(e,rejected_reason,',').extract('//text()')),',') 
|| chr(10) /*new line char */ ||
rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement(e,cnt,',').extract('//text()')),',') 
from (
  select part_name, 
         rejected_reason,
         row_number() over (partition by part_name, rejected_reason order by rejected_reason) as rn,
         count(*) over (partition by part_name, rejected_reason order by rejected_reason) as cnt
  from your_table
  order by part_name, 
         rejected_reason
)
where data_column = 'MAY 2014'
and rn = 1 -- to avoid duplicates in groups
group by part_name;
```

Comment: Thanks @Franek.I hope it will solve my problem.As of now I am unable to execute this query as my database version is 11.1.0.7.0 and LISTAGG function is available from Oracle 11g Release 2.

Comment: @Franek-Please have a look at it.I edited my question.

Comment: @Franek-Yes I replaced count(*) with sum(rejected_quantity).It is working fine but I was thinking if it is possible to get the output exactly in the format which I have posted in my question.

Comment: I don't have currently time to inspect but maybe this thread: https://community.oracle.com/thread/883038 could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table_name
PIVOT (COUNT(REJECTED_REASON)
FOR REJECTED_REASON IN('reason1', 'reason2', 'reason3' ....))
;
```

Comment: This query is static.Rejected Reasons are not fixed.Anyways Thanks @Khurram Ilyas

Answer (score 0):

Pls copy/paste to see results.

```
SELECT part_name    
 , sum(decode(reject_reason, 'Metal chips in port face', 1, 0)) "Metal chips in port face"
 , sum(decode(reject_reason, 'Angular hole Shrinkage', 1, 0)) "Angular hole Shrinkage"
 , sum(decode(reject_reason, '5th cap side dross', 1, 0)) "5th cap side dross"
 , sum(decode(reject_reason, 'Casting broken', 1, 0)) "Casting broken"
 , sum(decode(reject_reason, 'Bend in dand', 1, 0)) "Bend in dand"
 , sum(decode(reject_reason, 'Bend in casting', 1, 0)) "Bend in casting"
FROM
(
SELECT '03-03-2014' create_date, 'Metal chips in port face'  reject_reason,'PEGEOUT 1.8 CYLINDER HEAD CASTING H29' part_name FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT '03-03-2014', 'Angular hole Shrinkage', 'PEGEOUT 1.8 CYLINDER HEAD CASTING H29' FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT '01-05-2014', '5th cap side dross', 'CYL. HEAD VM MOTORI-4 CYL TESTA CILINDRI LAVORATA' FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT '01-05-2014', '5th cap side dross', 'CYL. HEAD VM MOTORI-4 CYL TESTA CILINDRI LAVORATA' FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT '01-05-2014', 'Casting broken'    , 'CYL. HEAD VM MOTORI-4 CYL TESTA CILINDRI LAVORATA' FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT '01-05-2014', 'Bend in dand', 'CYL. HEAD VM MOTORI-4 CYL TESTA CILINDRI LAVORATA' FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT '01-05-2014', 'Bend in casting', 'CYL. HEAD VM MOTORI-4 CYL TESTA CILINDRI LAVORATA' FROM dual
)
GROUP BY part_name
ORDER BY 1, 3
/
```

OR

```
SELECT part_name
 , MAX(CASE WHEN reject_reason = 'Metal chips in port face' THEN cnt END) "Metal chips in port face"
 , MAX(CASE WHEN reject_reason = 'Angular hole Shrinkage' THEN cnt END) "Angular hole Shrinkage"
 , MAX(CASE WHEN reject_reason = '5th cap side dross' THEN cnt END) "5th cap side dross"
 , MAX(CASE WHEN reject_reason = 'Casting broken' THEN cnt END) "Casting broken"
 , MAX(CASE WHEN reject_reason = 'Bend in dand' THEN cnt END) "Bend in dand"
 , MAX(CASE WHEN reject_reason = 'Bend in casting' THEN cnt END) "Bend in casting"
FROM (
  SELECT part_name
   , reject_reason
   , count(*) over (partition by part_name, reject_reason order by reject_reason) as cnt
 FROM (
SELECT '03-03-2014' create_date, 'Metal chips in port face'  reject_reason, 'PEGEOUT 1.8 CYLINDER HEAD CASTING H29' part_name FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT '03-03-2014', 'Angular hole Shrinkage', 'PEGEOUT 1.8 CYLINDER HEAD CASTING H29' FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT '01-05-2014', '5th cap side dross', 'CYL. HEAD VM MOTORI-4 CYL TESTA CILINDRI LAVORATA' FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT '01-05-2014', '5th cap side dross', 'CYL. HEAD VM MOTORI-4 CYL TESTA CILINDRI LAVORATA' FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT '01-05-2014', 'Casting broken'    , 'CYL. HEAD VM MOTORI-4 CYL TESTA CILINDRI LAVORATA' FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT '01-05-2014', 'Bend in dand', 'CYL. HEAD VM MOTORI-4 CYL TESTA CILINDRI LAVORATA' FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT '01-05-2014', 'Bend in casting', 'CYL. HEAD VM MOTORI-4 CYL TESTA CILINDRI LAVORATA' FROM dual
))
GROUP BY part_name
ORDER BY 1
/
```

Comment: Thanks @Art.But both these queries are static.Rejected Reasons are not fixed.I need a dynamic query

Comment: Hi, I think the only way to fix the dynamic columns problem is to create a table with column sequence, column name and report name (in case there are more then one such report). I had similar task in the past and this was the solution. Then you would select the columns names (by sequence or such) instead of typing them. I do not see or know any other way to resolve this. You type the column names or you need some structure to select the columns from.The rest is up to you. Regards, Art.

Comment: okay thanks @Art.My requirement got changed now.Please have a look at it.Will it make any difference in terms of coding.